# associated folder when saving an html file

Tags: html, windows-xp, save

When you save an html file "completely"(as opposite to "just html"), the html file and an associated resource folder will be saved. The interesting thing is that when you delete the html file, the folder will be deleted automatically.

The folder must not be some ordinary folder. What is it called and is it possible to do this programmatically?

I googled a bit but cannot find the answer because I don't even know what keywords should I type as I haev no idea what this is called.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the Microsoft term for this special folder is a 'Connected File', and I think it was introduced in Windows 2000 — in other words, it's a Windows/Explorer feature rather than an Internet Explorer feature. I haven't seen much about it, but this MSDN document could be a good starting point:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887(VS.85).aspx#connected

Answer (score 0):

Are you deleting this from Windows Explorer? I think it is a feature of that program, and not operating system. Try to delete it with any other file manager: FAR, Total Commander, etc

Comment: Rename the folder and it will lose its behavior, if you need to brake them appart. BUT the question above is how to create this connection programmatically, how to reproduce this behaviour.